# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable pymongo

Tags: pymongo, discord.py

So i am trying make it to where it checks the database and if they are in the database it sends a embed that say "User is already whitelisted" and if they aren't in the database then it adds them to the database. I keep getting the error `NoneType' object is not subscriptable` and i am lost at this point, any help will be useful.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['wl'])
@commands.has_role("Database")
async def Whitelist(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    member_id = member.id
    result = Collection.find_one({"User Id": member_id },{ "_id": 0, "Key": 1})
    KeyAdd = random.randint(23525623, 23623423426)
    displayname = member.display_name
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Whitelisted")
    remove_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Blacklisted")
    AddWhitelist = {"User Id":member_id, "Display Name": displayname, "Key": f"Zelly_{KeyAdd}"}

    embed2 = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Whitelist Error",
        color = discord.Colour(color)
    )
    embed2.add_field(name = "Content", value = f"{member.mention} is already whitelisted", inline = False)
    embed2.set_footer(text = f'{bot_name}')
    embed2.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()


    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Whitelist Successful",
        color = discord.Colour(color)
    )
    embed.add_field(name = "Content", value = f"Successfully whitelisted {member.mention}", inline = False)
    embed.set_footer(text = f'{bot_name}')
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    embed1 = discord.Embed(
        title = f"Whitelist",
        color = discord.Colour(color)
    )
    embed1.add_field(name = "Content", value = f"You have been whitelisted for Zelly", inline = False)
    embed1.add_field(name = "Key", value = result["Key"], inline = False)
    embed1.set_footer(text = f'{bot_name}')
    embed1.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    if Collection.find_one({"User Id": member_id },{ "_id": 0, "Key": 1}) == None:
        Added = Collection.insert_one(AddWhitelist)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    elif Collection:
        await ctx.send(embed = embed2)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full traceback for the error? Otherwise it's not possible to tell where the error's coming from. Although I suspect it might be from `value = result["Key"]`. If it is that, then you need to make sure that your collections actually contain the data you think they do. It sounds like it's not finding an entry from `Collection.find_one({"User Id": member_id },{ "_id": 0, "Key": 1})`.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, everything worked fine until i added
```if Collection.find_one({"User Id": member_id },{ "_id": 0, "Key": 1}) == None:
        Added = Collection.insert_one(AddWhitelist)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    elif Collection:
        await ctx.send(embed = embed2)
```
and if i take out ```
Added = Collection.insert_one(AddWhitelist) ``` 
and add it to the top it works.

Comment: Assuming error is on line that says `result["Key"]`... If you're getting a NoneType error then mongodb probably didn't return a dict that has "Key". Use an if statement to check before you set Before the line that has result["Key"] maybe use an if statement to chacke if the variable "result" returns None (Which probably is since you're gettign that error)